# How can I retrieve page reviews/ratings via Facebook Graph API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am trying to pull back an array of customer reviews (ratings?) from a particular facebook page.

I understand I need the `manage_pages` permission to do this, however according to the facebook docs I need to submit my app for review, providing the steps needed to reproduce the use of this permission, along with a screencast of the permission in use.

The problem I'm having is that I cannot use the permission to provide the steps and screencast because any attempt to do so results in the API telling me that it needs that permission. So a bit of a paradox really.

I assume there must be some kind of way to reproduce the steps needed in a test environment, but setting up a test app and using the `app_id` and `app_secret` from the test app still resulted in the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthorizationException' with message '(#200) Requires manage_pages permission to manage the object'

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $test_app_id,
  'app_secret' => $test_app_secret,
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.8',
]);

if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    try {
      $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
      // When Graph returns an error
      echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
      // When validation fails or other local issues
      echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
      exit;
    }

    if (isset($accessToken)) {
      // Logged in!
      $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;
    }
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['facebook_access_token'])) {
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    $permissions = ['manage_pages'];
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($site_url.'/fb-test.php', $permissions);
    echo '<a href="' . $loginUrl . '" target="_blank">Log in with Facebook!</a>';
    exit;
}
$access_token = $_SESSION['facebook_access_token'];

$response = $fb->get('/'.$page_id.'?fields=access_token', $access_token);
$page_access_token = $response->getDecodedBody()['access_token'];

$ratings = $fb->get('/'.$page_id.'/ratings', $page_access_token);

var_dump($ratings);
```

**Edit (following comment from luschn)**

I have altered my code to include the following, but I still get told that `manage_pages` permission is required.

```
<?php
$response = $fb->sendRequest(
    'GET',
    '/'.$page_id.'?fields=access_token',
    array (
        'user' => $user_id,
        'role' => 'administrators',
        'state' => rand(0,9999999)
    ),
    $access_token
);
$page_access_token = $response->getDecodedBody()['access_token'];

$response = $fb->sendRequest(
    'GET',
    '/'.$page_id.'/ratings',
    array (
        'user' => $user_id,
        'role' => 'administrators',
    ),
    $page_access_token
);
echo '<pre>'.print_r($response,true).'</pre>';
exit;
```

Comment: you can use any permission without review as user with a role in the app

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Comment: @luschn Please see my edit above. Perhaps you could suggest how my code could be changed if it is incorrect?

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, that is helpful. However, I still don't understand how to bypass the need for the `manage_pages` permission as an admin role user. My best guess was the code above in the edit, but that didn't work and I still got refused with the permission message.

Comment: You don’t bypass the permission - the user still needs to grant it to your app. Try and remove the app completely from the user account settings (https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications), and then try again to login and ask for the permission.

Comment: @CBroe The one adminstrator user for the app (me, also and administrator of the page) is the only one I will every use to access the reviews. What is the process for showing the api that I am already an administrator, or to grant the permission as you mentioned?

Comment: There is no need to specifically “show” that to the API. All you need to do is ask for the permission in the normal way - via the login dialog.

Comment: @CBroe That's what I did in my code above, which is where it tells me I need to submit the app for review, hence my dilemma

Comment: You need to submit it for review before you can ask users that do not have a role in the app for it - that is all that message in the login dialog is trying to tell you. Since you are the app admin, you can still continue with the login.

Comment: GOT IT!! - The ratings are coming through, thanks for you patience and help @CBroe